# RSA encryption causing IllegalBlockSizeException in Java

Tags: java, spring, encryption, public-key-encryption

After generating an AES key using:

```
keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
keyGenerator.init(256);
keyGenerator.generateKey();
```

I'm concatenating this key with a 16 byte IV, then encoding

```
public String encode(byte[] content) {
    return Base64.encodeBase64String(content);
 }
```

I pass this string to an RSA cipher as follows

```
private final Cipher publicKeyCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
publicKeyCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
publicKeyCipher.doFinal(content.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

All this works fine as expected and tests work fine. But when load testing on a controlled environment the doFinal function throws

```
{"log":"javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Data must not be longer than 245 bytes\n"}
```

This occurs about 0-15% of 500,000 requests. Logs show string length and byte size are always fixed at 70 meaning under 245.
So I don't think it's an encoding issue, I printed the string before encrypting it from one of the failed instances and tested it in a unit test which passed with no issues.

Comment: This could be bug in your JCE, but it could also be a bug in your code. 32 byte key + 16 byte IV makes 48 bytes. If base64 encoded, it should be 64 and not 70. Can you create an [mcve] which demonstrates you issue?

Comment: For the reference, may be useful https://www.knowledgefactory.net/2020/10/RSA%20%20AES%20a%20double%20layer%20security%20system%20-%20Architecture%20%20Implementation%20example%20.html

Comment: Btw, the currently shown code is fine.

Comment: There's no reason to base64 encode data *before* encrypting it.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can encrypt text(data to transfer) with AES and AES key with
   RSA.
2. Later you have to push RSA encrypted AES key and AES encrypted text
   to SERVER.
3. Also you need to decrypt AES key by RSA private.key and use that AES key
   to open text encrypted by AES algorithm.

This is pseudo code example.

```
    # Client side
    AESKey generatedAESKey = generateAESKey();
    byte[] encryptedText= generatedAESKey.encrypt("Some Text".getBytes())
    RsaEncrypted encryptedAES = RSA.encrypt(generatedAESKey); // by publickey.pem
    connection.sendServer(encryptedAES, encryptedText)
    
    # Server size
    EncryptedKeyAndData encryptedKeyAndData = connection.receive();
    AESKey aesKey = RSA.decrypt(encryptedKeyAndData.encryptedAES); // by privatekey.pem
    String text = aesKey.decrypt(encryptedKeyAndData.encryptedText);
```

I just recently finished socket programming usage of this implementation but I guess this is a spring related project. You don't have to implement raw client and server code. The main problem can be encoding.

Direct usage of InputStream and OutputStream can be problematic. So use ObjectStreams when transfering data(Encrypted AES Key, Text).

Comment: Yes it's a spring service and the approach you mentioned is what I've taken. 

I had a similar idea of it being an encoding issue so I logged the key to be encrypted, printing the size before encrypting it. It's consistently 70 bytes which is why I'm perplexed with the error.

Comment: How do you send encrypted text and aes key?

Comment: Once encrypted I send it in a http response

Comment: You can use object stream when sending to server. Just sen object and get object directly